# Installation: USB or DVD?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, windows-8, live-usb, livedvd

I wish to add Ubuntu 64 bit to Windows 8, and the installation guide mentions booting from USB or DVD. If I burn the downloaded Ubuntu to an empty USB stick, then put the stick into my computer, what happens next?

Comment: Please stop what you are doing and do your foot work. First, you should back up your data on Windows. Next read the install guide. Installing an new OS in a major change to your computer, and although it normally goes fine, data loss is a mouse click away. In addition you need to understand what you are doing with partitioning and UEFI

Comment: More guidance and more study is needed, yes. However, an answer which guides the new user is useful and not redundant.

Comment: Note for Windows 8 with UEFI secure boot etc, reading [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply writing ('burning' is a term reserved for making optical discs such as DVD-R and CD-R) the software folder to a USB stick will not make it bootable. [Burning a 'master' type DVD](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) with the ISO file you downloaded will make that DVD bootable. The procedure for USB is different.

Instead, for USB, install [UNETBOOTIN](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNetbootin) or another [USB Boot creation program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_to_create_Live_USB_systems) to a Windows machine. That UNETBOOOTIN-type program will extract the files from what you downloaded, and put them in their proper order on the USB flash drive [so you may boot from it](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live-USB).

Either way (and thanks to Wilf got mentioning this), please also read [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).h

Please make sure to also make a backup of your data from Windows first, and for good measure, also please [clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cloning) the entire Windows installation using [Clonezilla](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla) or [some other cloning program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_cloning_software), for easy restoration if something goes wrong.